# How to use SHL instruction reg, mem

Tags: assembly, masm32

I am currently using Kip Irvine's MASM32. I am attempting to use the SHL instruction with ebx, count-1 where count is a variable. Is there any way around this issue?!

Comment: The two operand form of SHL doesn't take a memory operand as the source (second operand). It can take an 8 bit immediate or register _CL_ , You will have to put count-1 into cl and then use SHL reg, cl . See http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html

Comment: Are you trying to load from the address `[count - 1]`, or do you want a shift-count of one less than the value stored at `[count]`?  cad's answer is assuming the former, since that's what you'd get if `shl` had a `shl r32, r/m32` encoding, instead of variable shift-counts only in `cl`

Answer (score 5):

Lesseee... taking a look at [my favorite x86 instruction reference](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html), we effectively end up with shifting by

1. one bit. *Only one operand required.*
2. a number of bits stored in an **immediate operand**. If you know the shift count at assembly time, **use this**. If not, you could still use it by using self-modifying code but that might be forbidden by the OS and is ugly.
3. `CL` bits.

The 3<sup>rd</sup> seems best suited in your case.<sup>1</sup>
Use

```
MOV CL, count-1
SHL EBX, CL
```

However, this assumes that `count-1` **is a byte variable**.

---

<sup>1</sup> We actually have too little information to know if the other options are feasible too or even better. After all, **use the one most convenient for you**.

Comment: This ended up working for me. Count was a DWORD variable but i changed it to a BYTE which didn't cause any problems.